# Getting error when trying to search for words within a String (Java)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
package wordfinderurl;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Wordfinderurl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // connect to website and output html to a string
   URL leagueoflegends = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(leagueoflegends.openStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
    // search the word "new" in the String inputLine 
    if(inputLine.contains("new")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "word found");
   }else{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "word not found");
}

}
}
```

I am trying to make a program that reads the html from a website and puts it into a string. Then I wanted to search for words within the String with the html from the website. When I execute the program I get the error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at wordfinderurl.Wordfinderurl.main(Wordfinderurl.java:19)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "nullPointerException" almost *ALWAYS* means "Whoops!  I forgot to initialize something!"  In your case, look at the variable(s) used in line 19, and figure out which of them might be uninitialized.  HINT: what would happen if, for whatever reason, you can't do an "openStream()"  of http://www.google.com?  HINT: what does your code do when "inputLine" is null?  HINT" Maybe you should have braces after your "while()" line, and maybe you should call `inputLine.contains()` *inside* of the "while)" loop (*before* inputLine becomes null)?

Comment: It is not a good idea to read the output of a web page in lines. There might be no line break in html and even if it is, you dont want to search the word in just anywhere of the page. There are special HTML parsers for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown in line 19. I assume that it is this line:

```
    if(inputLine.contains("new")) ...
```

Here you set `inputLine` as `readLine` until it is `null`.

```
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Thus, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Easy, but ugly, workaround could be (I'm tired as hell, so forgive any mistakes):

```
String inputLine;
String tmp;
while ((tmp = in.readLine()) != null)
    inputLine = tmp;
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
// search the word "new" in the String inputLine 
if(inputLine.contains("new")){
```

I'm sure others have nicer ways to treat it.